# How can I remake databases without losing data on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Sorry that this question is not a proper one on this site, but I really thought that I needed to know how to do that, because in production environment, if I delete all data all the time when I delete a model, this should be a serious problem.

### In detail

In case re-making the same named model,I mean after delete a model, then make the same named model.
It should be like 
`rails destroy model Name`
and after that 
`rails g model Name`
And usually errors occur in this case, we can basically fix the errors by using the command `rails db:schema:load`, but this command destroys whole data of an existing database, but I don't want to lose the data so I wonder if there are any other good ways for this.
Thanks

Comment: Its extremely unclear what you are asking. Could you elaborate a little more.

Comment: I updated my question thanks

Comment: Why do you need to delete a model?

Comment: Because once I thought that one model was necessary but after that I found that it was necessary

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this should not affect your production database, since Ruby on Rails knows what migrations have run already and that's why you should use `rails db:migrate` to update your database.

If your production database has old entries that you want to reuse, you can also change the [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) so that the affected table does not get dropped and recreated but altered instead.

Comment: I actually once tried the `rake db:migrate` but it didn't work by saying there's already a relation....  that's why I rebuild the databases, so I wonder if there's another way except re-making the databases.